# How to find running/stop service in my SQL Server Configuration?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server 2012 on my system. But when I tried to access SQL Server Configuration, I couldn't see SQL Service running on my system. How do I ensure it's running?

[image]

Comment: Start > Run > type services.msc > OK. In the list of services, you will see Microsoft SQL Server and related services. Ensure that all those services are in Started state. Refresh or close-and-reopen configuration manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will bet you installed the SQL Tools, but not the Engine itself.  Search for file "sqlservr.exe" on your local machine.  A standard/default installation will put it somewhere in the %ProgramFiles% folder (ie c:\program files\microsoft sql server\mssql.1....).  IF the file does *not* exist on your local machine, then the Engine feature was not checked/included, or the install itself failed, at which you should look at the setup log files.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, look at the setup log files to understand why it failed.  for SQL 2012, the setup log files should be located here - %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log.  You can look at the [msdn article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702(v=sql.110).aspx) for more info about the setup logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Windows Services** by

1) Go to start > Run and type services.msc

or by using the Windows Start-->Programs-->Administrative Tools-->Services menu.

Then, double-click (or right click) the MSSQLServer service, and right-click the required action.

[image]

Comment: 1)U couldnt find SQLserver(Instancename) in Services?                          2)When u installed your SQL sever?

Comment: Yapppp -w- i dont know why this is happend -w- ... I want publish my database from Microsoft Visual Studio butt something error like this : 
http://i.imgur.com/i10buZM.png

Comment: When u installed your SQL sever?this the first time

Comment: Uhmmm no,, First , im installed SQL Server 2005 ,, and the same problem appeared,, and thenn im installed SQL Server 2012  ,, and the same problem too :"

Comment: I think there is problem in installation..that's y u couldn't find the services.Better re install and try or use any other valid setup(which already working fine)